Boundary line with pattern in pgfplots
How do I obtain a line similar to this one in pgfplots? Basically a line, with some pattern on one side of it


Please show us the code you have so far ...

I don't have any code @Mensch

Then you should create some code. You need to show a Minimal Working Example. In this case, you need to construct a graph with a curve, so that a solution to your problem can be shown with that code.

Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as \documentclass{}...\begin{document} etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a minimal working example (MWE) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

You can use the border decoration provided by the decorations.pathreplacing library:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
    boundary/.style={
        postaction={
            decoration={
                border,
                amplitude=-7.5pt,
                segment length=5pt
            },
            decorate
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[boundary, domain=0:4.5, samples=100] {x*x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


If you want to skip the decoration at the start and end of the path:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
    boundary/.style={
        postaction={
            decoration={
                border,
                amplitude=-7.5pt,
                segment length=5pt,
                pre length=1cm,
                post length=1cm
            },
            decorate
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[boundary, domain=0:4.5, samples=100] {x*x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Also, there are probably already some relevant answers on this site which you could refer to, such as this one, which is probably a bit too complex for your needs.

If you want to change, for example, the amplitude locally, you could make use of passing an argument to the key:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
    boundary/.style={
        postaction={
            decoration={
                border,
                amplitude=-#1,
                segment length=5pt,
                pre length=1cm,
                post length=1cm
            },
            decorate
        }
    },
    boundary/.default=7.5pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[boundary=10pt, domain=0:4.5, samples=100] {x*x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



that's fantastic, exactly what I wanted, thanks! Is there any way to make the amplitude a variable so that I can vary its size and alginment?

@cedi123 It is a regular PGF key so you can use it as such.

\addplot[boundary, domain=3:15, samples=100, postaction={decoration={amplitude=10pt}}] {7};
doesn't change anything and
\addplot[boundary, domain=3:15, samples=100, amplitude=10pt] {7};
throws an error that tikz does not know the key
@Jasper Habicht

@cedi123 See my edit. You might want to learn a bit more about how to pass arguments to PGF keys ... maybe this can get you in the right direction. Check the manual for more information. It is very detailed, but also very helpful.
